# Yii2 rest Api for mobile with session ip-address not working

Tags: php, rest, session, yii2

I have worked on web-based rest API but this the first time I am creating Rest API for mobile apps. I am trying to send SMS code to user posted mobile number. SMS code is saved in session with user ip-address.

Next step, user send the SMS code. Rest API compare posted SMS code in the session.

Here is my code for sending SMS and validating SMS code:

```
 //send sms code here
 public function actionSendSms(){
   $this->response['success'] = false;
   $model = $this->loadPostData('step1phone');
   $phone = str_replace('+','',Yii::$app->request->post('phone'));
   $model->phone = urlencode(preg_replace('/[^\d\+]/', '', $phone));
   if(Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->validate()){
     $code = Yii::$app->helper->generateRandomString(4);
     Yii::$app->sms->setMessage($code);
     $sms = Yii::$app->sms->send($model->phone);
     if($sms->status){
        $ipAddress = Yii::$app->request->getUserIP();
        Yii::$app->session->set('phone-'.$ipAddress, $code);
        $this->response['success'] = true;
    }else{
        $this->response['errorMessage'] = $sms->errorMessage;
    }
  }else{
    $this->response['status'] = 'error';
    $this->response['errors'] = $model->getErrors(); //@TODO
  }
  return $this->response;
}
//sms code validation here
public function actionSendSmsCode()
{
    $ipAddress = Yii::$app->request->getUserIP();
    \Yii::info('User IP - '.$ipAddress, 'mylog');
    $model = $this->loadPostData('step1phoneVerify');
    if($model->validate()){
      $this->response['status'] = true;
      $this->response['data'] = [
          'code' => Yii::$app->session->get('phone-'.$ipAddress),
          'postValue' => Yii::$app->request->post('phoneVerificationCode'),
      ];
        \Yii::info('code - '.Yii::$app->session->get('phone-'.$ipAddress), 'mylog');
        \Yii::info('postValue - '.Yii::$app->request->post('phoneVerificationCode'), 'mylog');
        \Yii::info('User IP - '.Yii::$app->request->getUserIP(), 'mylog');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response['status'] = 'error';
        $this->response['error'] = $model->getErrors();
        $this->response['data'] = [
            'code' => Yii::$app->session->get('phone-'.Yii::$app->request->getUserIP()),
            'postValue' => Yii::$app->request->post('phoneVerificationCode'),
        ];
        \Yii::info('code - '.Yii::$app->session->get('phone-'.$ipAddress), 'mylog');
        \Yii::info('postValue - '.Yii::$app->request->post('phoneVerificationCode'), 'mylog');
        \Yii::info('User IP - '.Yii::$app->request->getUserIP(), 'mylog');
    }
    \Yii::info('Session - '. json_encode(Yii::$app->session) , 'mylog');
    //$this->$this->response['session'] = Yii::$app->session->get('phone-'.$ipAddress);
    return $this->response;
}

//Model used for validation.
public function validateSmsCode($attribute, $params)
{
    $ipAddress = Yii::$app->request->getUserIP();
    if(!empty($this->phoneVerificationCode) && $this->phoneVerificationCode != Yii::$app->session->get('phone-'.$ipAddress))
    {
        $this->addError('phoneVerificationCode', Yii::t('app', 'SMS code doesn`t match.'));
    }
}
```

When I try testing my code from post Rest API service, everything works fine.
But from mobile apps, is never get validate even I post correct SMS code.

When I try to see in my log file." code -" is empty but "User IP -" get ip-address of the user.

Again here if I use post rest API service, in the log file I get the info as excepted. My frontend for my apps is Android.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: in mobile connections, ip can change frequently, so you avoid to check that ip is the same when started the session.

Comment: I cannot use the database. so what can be the best option for this scenario?any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake that you used IP address as secure and static value which is wrong.

**IP address:** The user IP address is not unique per user as there are a limited number, so usually multiple user shared same IP, NAT public IP address, read more about NAT but keep in mind user IP is shared and can change and attacker can spoof it.

**php session:** are data that are usually stored on server (not true in all cases). So the server send a key to the client as secure token, and each time the client with send this token in cookies so the server can load the session. So you don't need the IP you Already have the secure token.

**Saving data to session:**

```
Yii::$app->session->set('phone', $model->phone);
Yii::$app->session->set('code', $code);
//Just use key (static string) to store in session as this session in unique per user
```

**reading data from session:**

```
$phone = Yii::$app->session->get('phone');
$code = Yii::$app->session->get('code');
//Just use key that you used to store the data
```

I advice to read more about Yii2 session [YII2 session guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies)

Keep in mind that you should send session id in all requests using cookies. Also in APP development sessions are rarely used and they usually use rest authorization like auth2 and cache to store data on server.

**Session Example:** suppose we have this code

```
public function actionPageCount(){
    if(Yii::$app->session->get('count'))
        Yii::$app->session->set('count',Yii::$app->session->get('count')+1);
    else
        Yii::$app->session->set('count',1);

    return Yii::$app->session->get('count');
}
```

First time the user call this action the if statement will be false because the user doesn't have a session id, so in else the web app will create a new session and will set count to 1. When the session is created the server will send to the browser or app this header.

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=rl721ac6h3vfgld5repf8pcjl6; path=/; HttpOnly
```

which mean create new cookie named PHPSESSID with value of rl721ac6h3vfgld5repf8pcjl6. So when the user call the action again. The server will load the session based on the session id. And if the user didn't include the session id the server will create new session. Call this method from a browser and see the behavior then open and new private tab and call it again and see that the server will manage the session for you. In app you have to save the session id and added as cookie in each request.

Comment: What if more than 2 users are using the apps at the same time? The session can be overridden.

Comment: No the session per user not app so if you have 100 user the server will have 100 session. But you need to send session id in the cookies

Comment: Can you please provide me some hints about send session id in the cookies?